# Can a DI object be both a client and a service simultaneously?

Tags: dependency-injection

In my reasearch of Dependendcy Injection so far I haven't seen an example object being treated as both a client and a service (meaning a service [value, factory, etc] which has its own dependencies).

**Can a component be both a client and a service without breaking some fundamental aspect of DI?** Is this normal to do in DI?

For clarification, I'm asking if a component can both *be* a dependency, and *have* dependencies, making it both a client and a service in Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Think of the classic DI example - a Logger - which itself might take dependencies on a FileSystemWriter and a DatabaseWriter.